# Wget works for some websites but not for others?

Tags: wget, centos8

I am on centos 8 and using the wget command to download some files, I am able to do so on certain websites but not on others. here is an example that works for me

```
wget https://forums.centos.org/index.php
--2021-07-26 20:50:40--  https://forums.centos.org/index.php
Resolving forums.centos.org (forums.centos.org)... 35.178.235.168
Connecting to forums.centos.org (forums.centos.org)|35.178.235.168|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.php’

index.php                                                                         [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                                            ]  49.80K   319KB/s    in 0.2s

2021-07-26 20:50:41 (319 KB/s) - ‘index.php’ saved [50997]
```

and here is an example that doesn't

```
wget -d https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastq_screen/_build/html/index.html
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.5 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/tuser1/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2021-07-26 20:27:16--  https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastq_screen/_build/html/index.html
Certificates loaded: 147
Resolving www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk (www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk)... 149.155.133.4
Caching www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk => 149.155.133.4
Connecting to www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk (www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk)|149.155.133.4|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
```

EDIT: I have tried pinging as well, I can ping yahoo.com but cannot ping google.com. Some websites are working some are not with ping as well.

I have disabled the firewall (firewalld) and tried to use the curl -O command as well to download but have not found a solution for this. Please let me know if there is any way to fix this

Comment: ping? traceroute? tcptraceroute?

Comment: What is the output of `telnet 149.155.133.4 443`?

Comment: telnet output is 

telnet 149.155.133.4 443
Trying 149.155.133.4...
telnet: connect to address 149.155.133.4: Connection timed out

Comment: results of ping ping www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk
PING www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk (149.155.133.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2044ms

results of traceroute & tcptraceroute for #9-10 are just ***